# Issue loading external properties(which is added to classpath) in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, properties, classpath, external

I need to load the application properties externally into my Springboot application. In my production system; we are adding the properties to classpath; so to replicate that I am adding the properties file to my class path and trying to load the properties using the @PropertyResource in SpringBoot but it is not loading

Using eclipse; I have added the properties file to my classpath(added the file to buildpath)
With Springboot and using @PropertyResource; the application is failing to load the properties.

```
@SpringbootApplication
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFoind=true,value="classpath:myapp.properties")
public class MyApp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
              springApplication.run(MyApp.class,args);

    }
}


@Service
public class myService{

@Value("${name}")
private String name;

       private void printName() {
          System.out.println(" Name:"+name);
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for @PropertySource to work you have to configure a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.  Add this to your MyApp class:

```java
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfig() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Also of note - ignoreResourceNotFoind is misspelled in your example (foind -> found)